# Is using a single class as both a Context Manager and a Decorator frowned upon?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, contextmanager

I heard a discussion between 2 developers, one was against having the same object serve both as a context manager and a decorator.
His argument was that decorators are meant to enhance\wrap a function, and context managers simply manage data or state when performing an action.

**Is there a common agreement\disagreement about this?**

I personally like having both options in a single object.
Here's a rough example of what I mean:

```
class Example(object):
    """Context manager AND decorator"""
    def __enter__(self):
        return "Entering"
    
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return "Exiting"
    
    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with self:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

with Example():
    # run something
    some_function()

@Example
def some_function():
    pass
```

Comment: Well if the functionality is the same for both, else I don't see issues other than possible prompting to high coupling and not doing separation of concerns.

Comment: The standard library has several examples of things usable as both, for example [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch).

Comment: This question probably doesn't fit StackOverflow as you are asking for opinions.

Even as an opinion one can probably not answer it well in general. The question is whether it makes sense for the use-case. Would someone not reading the documentation expect the behavior of the context manager and decorator given the name? If not, would it get away with less documentation if you used two separate names? (The goal is not to be clever, but to be simple)

Comment: Yes, this was more of a debate (is there a better place for that? I'm not familiar enough with stackoverflow).  Thanks for the comments and the example, it helped to see the implementation for mock.patch: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/unittest/mock.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was more of a debate than a question with an specific answer.
Someone mentioned an example from one of the built-in Python modules: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/unittest/mock.py

I'll accept this as an answer since I was mostly looking for opinions on this.
Thanks to those who commented!